# Microsoft Actionable Messages through API

Tags: java, email, outlook, actionable-notification

Is there any way to send the actionable messages (like Sending "Approve", "Reject" buttons within an email) using APIs of the Microsoft? Other than integrating with Connectors..

I have program that sends out bulk mails to end users, however, I would like to add these buttons into it and make it much easier for users by allowing them to approve the requests in mail itself that reflects back into the application it's needed to do.

Any inputs are greatly appreciated!

Thank You in advance :)